# Select funciona no localhost porém não funciona no servidor

Tags: php, mysql, select

O `select` estava funcionando normalmente no wamp, porém ao fazer o upload do site para o servidor as informações de algumas p'ginas simplesmente pararam de vir.

A única parte em que o `select`está funcionando é na de login da área administrativa, já verifiquei o meu arquivo de conexão e todas as informações batem com as do servidor, no `select` o mesmo.

Segue o código de uma das páginas :

```
include 'conexao.php';

// Selecionando informações da tabela galeriafotos
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `galeriafotos` order by datacadastro DESC";
//Selecionando informações da tabela projetos
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `projetos` order by datacadastro DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

$resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql2);
```

E as chamo na página através do seguinte código:

```
  <?php foreach($resultado as $linha) { ?>
       <tr>
       <td>
  <?php echo $linha["titulo"]; ?>
       </td>
       <td>
  <?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($linha['datacadastro'])); ?>
        </td>
         <td>
         <?php echo $linha["categoria"]; ?>
          </td>

                                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54253/discussion-on-question-by-vinicius-zable-select-funciona-no-localhost-porem-nao)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela demonstração do código na pergunta, faltou fazer o `fetch()` por isso o print_r de $resultado exibia `mysqli_result Object ( )`

```
include 'conexao.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `galeriafotos` order by datacadastro DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
```

Arquivo de view

```
<?php foreach($resultado as $linha) { ?>
```

O correto é:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `galeriafotos` order by datacadastro DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

$itens = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Ou alternativamente:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `galeriafotos` order by datacadastro DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$lista = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
   $lista[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar o PDO ao invés do mysqli_query.

exemplo:
Para realizar a conexão.

```
 <?php $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seubancodedados', 'root', 'senha');pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);?>
```

Exemplo do Select

```
<?php $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM galeriafotos order by datacadastro DESC");?>
```

para exibir o resultado

```
<?php while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {      echo Nome: {$linha['nome']} - Usuário: {$linha['usuario']}<br />";}?>
```

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta. O.o

Comment: Tentei,porém sem resultado,mas valeu a tentativa...

Answer (score 1):

Você deve se atentar ao seguinte:

1. Conferiu se o usuário, senha, servidor e porta estão corretos?
2. A tabela está exatamente igual ao ambiente de desenvolvimento?
3. Há registros na tabela do banco remoto?
4. O SQL funciona se você rodá-lo diretamente no banco remoto?
5. A aplicação que está no ambiente de desenvolvimento é a mesma que
   roda no ambiente de produção?

Comment: Sim,para todas...

Comment: seu banco remoto funciona para qualquer outra coisa? (inserts, updates, etc)

Comment: Sim,normalmente...